# Plotting Multiple Curves for a Solution of a Coupled Set of Equations

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I solve a coupled set of equations and then plot a function of the solution versus `m`. I would like to add a few curves on the same plot for different pairs of `fc1` and `fc2`. Here is my code:

Definitions

```
d = 0.1;
bet = 0.001;
mu = 0.001;
fc1 = (2/8)^2;
fc2 = (3/8)^2;
N1p = N1*(1 - m) + N2*m;
N2p = N2*(1 - m) + N1*m;
b1 = 1 - bet*N1p - fc1;
b2 = 1 - bet*N2p - fc2;
b1mut = 1 - bet*N1; b2mut = 1 - bet*N2;
```

Equations

```
eqns1 = {N1 == N1p*b1*2, N2 == N2p*b2*2 && N1 > 0 && N2 > 0,  m*(1 - b2mut) + (1 - m)*(1 - b1mut) + s1^2*(1 - m)*b1mut +  s2^2*m*b2mut == s1,  m*(1 - b1mut) 
+ (1 - m)*(1 - b2mut) + s2^2*(1 - m)*b2mut +  s1^2*m*b1mut == s2, s1 < 0.999 && s2 < 0.999} // Simplify;
```

Solving

```
soln = Flatten /@ Transpose[{m -> # & /@ Range[0, 1, 1/100], 
     Table[NSolve[eqns1, {N1, N2, s1, s2}, Reals], {m, 0, 1, 1/100}]}];
```

Plotting

```
fmPemerg =  Interpolation[{m, 1 - Exp[-mu*(N1*(1 - s1) + N2*(1 - s2))]} /. soln];

Plot[{fmPemerg[m]}, {m, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"m", " Pemerg"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple and fast way is to solve it with FindRoot

```
d = 0.1;
bet = 0.001;
mu = 0.001;
N1p = N1*(1 - m) + N2*m;
N2p = N2*(1 - m) + N1*m;
b1 = 1 - bet*N1p - fc1;
b2 = 1 - bet*N2p - fc2;
b1mut = 1 - bet*N1; b2mut = 1 - bet*N2;

 eqns2[N1_, N2_, s1_, s2_, m_, fc1_,fc2_] = {N1 == N1p*b1*2, N2 == N2p*b2*2, 
    m*(1 - b2mut) + (1 - m)*(1 - b1mut) + s1^2*(1 - m)*b1mut + 
 s2^2*m*b2mut == s1, 
    m*(1 - b1mut) + (1 - m)*(1 - b2mut) + s2^2*(1 - m)*b2mut + 
 s1^2*m*b1mut == s2} // Simplify

 fr1[m_?NumericQ, fc1_, fc2_] := 
   FindRoot[eqns2[N1, N2, s1, s2, m, fc1, fc2], {N1, 400}, {N2, 
     300}, {s1, .1}, {s2, .1}]

 fr1[.8, (2/8)^2, (3/8)^2]

(*    {N1 -> 423.579, N2 -> 368.679, s1 -> 0.650866,s2 -> 0.663541}   *)

 f = 1 - Exp[-mu*(N1*(1 - s1) + N2*(1 - s2))]

 Plot[{f /. fr1[m, (2/8)^2, (3/8)^2], f /. fr1[m, (2/8)^2, (4/8)^2], 
    f /. fr1[m, (2/8)^2, (5/8)^2]}, {m, 0, 1}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: What does `m_?NumericQ`  do?